# Methods of overlaying a plot on an existing plot

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have the plot below

```
par(mar=c(5.1,10.1,4.1,1.1))
plot(1,1, type="l", lwd=5, ylim=c(0,1), ylab="", xlab="Chi lab", lty=1, main="Overlay Plots", cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.25, cex.main=1.6, bty="n", xlim=c(-1,4), yaxt="n", xaxt="n")
axis(1, line = 1, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.25 , at=0:4)
axis(2, line = 4, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.25 )
mtext("Psi lab", las=3, side = 2, line = 7, cex=1.5)
points(rnorm(100, 2, 1), rnorm(100,0.5,0.2))
```

Between the yaxis and the zero of the x axis I would like to overlay the below plot

```
df<-c("III", "III", "I", "I", "I", "II", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
      "II", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "II", "I", "III", "II", 
      "II", "III", "I", "II", "II", "I", "I", "IV", "I", "III", "I", 
      "III", "I", "I", "II", "I", "II", "II", "I", "II", "I", "II", 
      "II", "II", "II", "I", "I", "II", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
      "II", "II", "III", "I", "III", "I", "I", "I", "I", "II", "I", 
      "II", "III", "I", "I", "I", "I", "III", "II", "II", "I", "I", 
      "II", "I", "II", "III", "II", "III", "II", "III", "I", "III", 
      "III")
barplot(as.matrix(table(df)*100/90), col=c("white", "gray70", "gray40", "black"), ylim=c(0,100))
```

How can this be done in R? Please base R solutions only.

Thanks

Comment: Overlay it as is, with a separate y axis, or are you trying to match y scales? Note that `barplot` has an `add` argument.

Comment: I would like that the the barplot will extend from the 0 to 1 of the y axis of the first plot. No separate y axis. However I am open to overlaying solutions (just like photoshop, putting an image "on-top" of another image. Thanks

Comment: Ok, but the bar plot is on a totally different scale (0-100) than the other plot (0-1). So some sort of rescaling will be necessary, otherwise the barplot will be huge.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thats why I am more tending towards an overlay solution than a "complex plot".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant on agstudy's approach, using `layout` directly for the whole plot. I've dispensed with many of the details of the plot, just to illustrate placing the two side-by-side:

```
m <- matrix(1:2,1,2)
layout(m,widths = c(0.25,0.75))

par(mar = c(5,4,4,0) + 0.1)
barplot(as.matrix(table(df)*100/90) / 100, 
                col=c("white", "gray70", "gray40", "black"), 
                ylim=c(0,1),
                ylab = "Psi Lab")
par(mar = c(5,0,4,2) + 0.1)
plot(rnorm(100,2,1),rnorm(100,0.5,0.2),
         xlab = "Chi Lab",ylab = "",
         bty = "n",yaxt = "n")
```

[image]

I saved the image wider than it is tall, to preserve the aspect ratio. The main advantage of using layout for both plots is that the 0 level is aligned better, I think.

This uses a simple 1 row, 2 column layout. For the first plot, I remove the right margin, and for the second plot I remove the left margin (except for the default padding). Obviously, I had to rescale the barplot data first, but that isn't terribly difficult. And the axes can be customized as before.

Comment: +1! the difference here that the axes are thoses of barplot not of the scatter plot.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really satisfied with this solution ( a little bit tricky). The idea is :

1. to plot the first plot
2. add a layout to plot only in the left side
3. play with margins to get the right barplot size
4. Overlap using `par(new=TRUE)` ( I tried with add=TRUE option without success)

Here my code:

```
## plot your first plot ....
## play with layout and margin to add barplot
par(mar=c(5.1,1,6,5))
nf <- layout(matrix(c(1,1,0,0), 2, 2), respect = TRUE)

par(new=TRUE) 
barplot(as.matrix(table(df)*100/90), col=c("white", "gray70", "gray40", "black"), 
        ylim=c(0,100),axes=F)
```

[image]

#### Edit : explain layout:

For the layout I am using this matrix:

```
matrix(c(1,1,0,0), 2, 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    0
```

And to see it , you can use the handy `layout.show`:

```
nf <- layout(matrix(c(1,1,0,0), 2, 2), respect = TRUE)
layout.show(nf)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Would you mind explaining with a few words the layout procedure? Thanks a lot!